# login to another website from client website

Tags: jsp, iframe, authentication, web

I'm developing a JSP/servelet web application. I'm displaying this website http://emma.msrb.org/Search/Search.aspx in one of my webpages using

```
<iframe width="825" height="800" src="http://emma.msrb.org/Search/Search.aspx"></iframe>
```

I want automatically to login to the this website as it loads to the `<iframe>`

The login is at top right corner of the website "MyEMMA", when i click the link it pop-up a window to login. Then enter email && passwd. By looking at the page-source underneath login function is a Javascript.

Is it possible to login to this website while loadin it to the ?
if so can anyone provide me some tips how to do that?

Comment: This is the content of the login pop-up http://codepad.org/GgQF1RMx. There is a java script executed when "Sign In" button pressed.  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$Masthead$UserAcct1$signInButton" value="Sign In" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$Masthead$UserAcct1$signInButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;UserAcctSignInValidation&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_Masthead_UserAcct1_signInButton" /> Can you tell how do I post to the serverlrt with these parameters

Answer (score 2):

just see the how the login java script function is written. In the sense , where it is posting the login credentials, and what are the parameters it is passing. Now when loading this page, first post the credentials on the same servlet , and then load this page.